# Angular Navigation is not routing to Ionic page after Firebase Authentication

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm still figuring out Angular Navigation/Routing. I'm having an issue with a page not loading after successfully authenticating a firebase user. My opening page is a basic login page, from which you can navigate to either a dashboard or a registration page. As far as I know, there is no html and initializing errors on any pages. The registration page does load and User Authentication works fine, but the dashboard just does not want to load. How do I fix this?

Here is my `login.page.html` layout :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="validations_form" (ngSubmit)="loginUser(validations_form.getRawValue())">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="validation-errors">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.email">
        <div class="error-message"
          *ngIf="validations_form.get('email').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('email').dirty || validations_form.get('email').touched)">
          {{ validation.message }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-controll" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="validation-errors">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
        <div class="error-message"
          *ngIf="validations_form.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('password').dirty || validations_form.get('password').touched)">
          {{ validation.message }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>

    <ion-button class="submit-btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!validations_form.valid">Log In</ion-button>

    <label class="error-message">{{errorMessage}}</label>
  </form>
  <p class="go-to-register">
    No account yet? <a (click)="goToRegisterPage()">Create an account.</a>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

And here is `login.page.ts` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {


  validations_form: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';

  user = {} as User;
  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private authService: AuthenticateService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.required
      ])),
    });
  }

  validation_messages = {
    'email': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' }
    ],
    'password': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' }
    ]
  };

  loginUser(user) {
    this.authService.loginUser(user)
      .then(res => {
        this.errorMessage = "";
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }, err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
      })
  }

  goToRegisterPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }

}
```

Here is `dashboard.page.html` layout :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar primary>
    <ion-title>Dashboard</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button id="logout" (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        Welcome to Dashboard!
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        Your Registered EmailID : 111
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and `dashboard.page.ts` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {

  userEmail: string;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private authService: AuthenticateService,
    public storage: Storage
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authService.userDetails().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('res', res);
      if (res !== null) {
        this.userEmail = res.email;
      } else {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('');
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log('err', err);
    })

  }


  logout() {
    this.authService.logoutUser()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}
```

And here is `authentication.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticateService {

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }

  registerUser(user: User) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

      this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(
          res => resolve(res),
          err => reject(err))
    })

  }

  loginUser(user: User) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(
          res => resolve(res),
          err => reject(err))
    })
  }

  logoutUser() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.afAuth.currentUser) {
        this.afAuth.signOut()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("LOG Out");
            resolve();
          }).catch((error) => {
            reject();
          });
      }
    })
  }

  userDetails() {
    return this.afAuth.user
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot preferable to use auth guard in your routing system.

[Auth Guard Tuto](https://www.joshmorony.com/prevent-access-to-pages-in-ionic-with-angular-route-guards/)

The way you have implemented your login check in your dashboard page is dangerous and an be easily bypassed.

Comment: Thats what i was planning on adding AuthGuard next, but thanks for the link @GregBzFullstack. I still don't understand why the dashboard won't load

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue wasn't in the navigation routes, it was instead an issue with importing Firebase Storage (which I didn't even use).